# How to run preview analysis locally, but disallow uploading to server?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

**SonarQube 5.6.1**

I need to allow users to run SonarQube analysis locally in preview mode, but I do not want them to be able to push anything to the server.

I see that there is this assignable ability:

> EXECUTE ANALYSIS Ability to get all settings required to perform an
>   analysis (including the secured settings like passwords) and to push
>   analysis results to the SonarQube server.

I need users to be able to do the first half of this:

> ...get all settings required to perform an analysis...

But not this part:

> ...push analysis results to the SonarQube server.

Comment: Can you specify which version of SonarQube you are running?

Comment: I forgot to include that. Sorry about that. It is updated now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With SonarQube 5.6.1, making it possible for users to run preview analyses but not push results to the server require the 2 following things:

- Those users don't have the global "Execute Analysis" permission
- Those users have the "Browse" permission on their projects

That's all they need.

Note that if your developers are using IntelliJ, Eclipse or Visual Studio, you should encourage them to use [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/) (connected to your SonarQube server) instead of running "preview" analyses manually. This will be far more efficient. And even if they don't have such IDE, they'd better use [SonarLint for CLI](http://www.sonarlint.org/commandline/index.html).

Comment: The target is Gradle. This would make a nice addition to the Gradle plugin. Having a task like sonarqubePreview. But that is a request for another place :-)

Comment: FYI, SonarLint for CLI is no longer supported.